# Inductive proof, k+1 step

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am solving a proof by induction in my calculus book and I'm having trouble with binomial conversions.

For example,

$$\binom{2n}{n} = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}^2$$

I've proven the base step for $n = 0$.  But I am having trouble with figuring out how I can express $\binom{2n}{n}$ if n were n + 1.  This would give a result of (I believe) $$\binom{2n+2}{n+1}$$.

I can't really figure out how to express this in terms of $\binom{2n}{n}$ so I can solve it via induction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use the following:
$$\binom{n+1}{r}=\binom{n}{r}+\binom{n}{r-1}.$$
For example:
$$\binom{2n+2}{n+1}=\binom{2n+1}{n+1}+\binom{2n+1}{n}.$$
Now reduce the $2n+1$ further to $2n$.

Note: There is a much simpler proof using counting arguments only: Let there be $n$ boys and $n$ girls. You want to make a team of $n$ players using boys and girls. In how many ways you can do it? Interpret it in two ways and you can get both sides of the equality.